# Run bundle exec <command> Tasks in Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, rspec, visual-studio-code

Following [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402084109/http://justinhhorner.com/adding-and-running-tasks-in-visual-studio-code/) tutorial on how to make a task for Rspec works great, in a clean working environment.

But I have multiple versions of RSpec installed and the task, correctly, gets confused which version to use.

So I want to use the following command:

`{ "command": "bundle exec rspec" }`

This fails though, with the following error:

```
Failed to launch external program bundle exec rspec .
spawn bundle exec rspec ENOENT
```

How can I define a (test) task to that runs `bundle exec rspec` instead of plain `rspec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hurelu in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046411/define-multiple-tasks-in-vscode) post, who explains how shell commands are constructed using the definitions in tasks.json, I have been able to define a tasks file that can run both rspec and cucumber, using bundle's exec:

```
{
  "command": "bundle",
  "args": ["exec"],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "suppressTaskName": true,
      "taskName": "rspec",
      "args": [ "rspec", "${file}" ],
      "isTestCommand": true
    },
    {
      "suppressTaskName": true,
      "taskName": "cucumber",
      "args": [ "cucumber", "${file}" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

RSpec is the test command, so you can use Cmd+Shift+T/Ctrl+Shift+t to run the current file as an RSpec test.

Happy coding!