# How can I define multiple tasks to run different commands?

Tags: typescript, configuration, visual-studio-code

**Duplicate Question?**

May be it is but I didn't find any answer. I reference some questions below. Which is related to my question.
[Question 1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/981),[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702041/multiple-commands-tasks-with-visual-studio-code),[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046411/define-multiple-tasks-in-vscode).

**Question Overview:**

In my task.json I wrote following code in which when I press ctrl + shift + B. Its shows output on my browser. Which works fine.

```
"version": "0.1.0",

"command": "chrome",

"windows": {
    "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
},

"args": ["index.html"]
```

In few days/ I am learning SASS and I need to integrate it with my VS Code. So, I found below configuration to add in tasks.json. [Reference Site](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/css)

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "node-sass",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["style.scss","style.css"]
}
```

**Problem:**
When I put SASS configuration in my tasks.json file. It shows me some errors.

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",

"command": "chrome",

"windows": {
    "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
},

"args": ["index.html"],

"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Transpile SASS into CSS", //my task name
        "command": "node-sass", //error, command is not allowed here
        "isShellCommand": true, //error, command is not allowed here
        "args": ["style.scss","style.css"]
    }
]

}
```

Question is how can I manage several tasks in VS Code. Please explain me what I am doing wrong.