# Run more than one task with default shortcut

Tags: node.js, typescript, build, visual-studio-code, task

In a project i use typescript to generate es6 for server side (node.js) and es5 for client side.
I've got a tsconfig.json and a tsconfigclient.json.
I've got two task in tasks.json to generate javascript :

```html
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfigclient.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Both could be run whith ctrl-shift-B ... but vscode ask me witch one to use ?
Is it possible to launch both in same time with ctrl-shift-b

Thanks.
PS : I'm begginer in node.js, typescript and vscode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a composite task that uses `dependsOn` to run the other two tasks:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build1",
            "identifier": "build1",         
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "label": "build2",
            "identifier": "build2",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfigclient.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "label": "Composite",
            "dependsOn": [
                "build1",
                "build2"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

You can also use a command line task to run more than one command. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290053/306149) has more info about that

Comment: Hello, I've just changed "label" by "taskName" in group "Composite". And it works. Thanks a lot.