# Visual Studio Code Task Argument

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, args

I'm trying to create some tasks in Visual Studio Code to run all the tests in my go project.

I usually execute the tests on the command line using:

```
go test ./...
```

In Visual Studio Code my tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "go",

    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "isBuildCommand": true
        },
        {
            "taskName": "test",
            "isTestCommand": true,
            "args": ["./..."]
        }
    ]
}
```

So Build works fine (CTRL + SHIFT + B)

But when I try to run the tests (CTRL + SHIFT + T) the following error occurs:

```
go: unknown subcommand "./..."
```

It seems to be omitting the "test" param, but when I comment out the args it runs go test fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like it's not getting a "test" argument. Can you check the actual command that is executed ?

Comment: Without the args it runs "go test". With the args in place it runs "go ./...".

Comment: I would imagine you need `["test", "./..."]`.

Comment: That's the other weird thing, adding test to the args as per above returns "can't load package: package test: cannot find package "test""

Comment: Reverse the task and args for a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## THIS MAY BE A BUG

---

### VSCode Reverse Args and Task as of v0.8.0

This may be a bug that still persists in the newer versions.  As of v0.9.1 I have not had a chance to test.  Prior to 0.9.1  at least one hack worked by reversing the task and it's arg as in the following example:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "go",

"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "isBuildCommand": true
    },
    {
        "taskName": "./...",
        "isTestCommand": true,
        "args": ["test"]
    }
  ]
}
```

It's hard to believe that this has still persisted until v0.8.0 so there may be a preferred solution that I have not discovered.

Here is a link to a prior post that deals with a similar issue:

[Define multiple tasks in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046411/define-multiple-tasks-in-vscode/31543908#31543908)

Scroll down to my answer for more explanation.