# VS Code tasks.json -- Tasks work individually, but not combined

Tags: json, go, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

This is driving me nuts (go nuts!). Build / run file is proper and fmt command is proper. But if I try to combine into one tasks file, it stops working.

These two work fine on their own and behave the way I want:

tasks.json

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"command": "go",
"taskName": "build",
"args": [
    "build",
    "-o",
    "${workspaceRoot}.exe",
    "&&",
    "${workspaceRoot}.exe"
],
"isBuildCommand": true
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"command": "go",
"taskName": "fmt",
"args": [
    "fmt",
    "${file}"
],
"isBuildCommand": true
}
```

But combined into one file, it will not work:

tasks.json

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"command": "go",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceRoot}.exe",
            "&&",
            "${workspaceRoot}.exe"
        ],
        "isBuildCommand": true
    },
    {
        "taskName": "fmt",
        "args": [
            "fmt",
            "${file}"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Error given on build:

```
can't load package: package build: cannot find package "build" in any of:
    D:\dev\Go\src\build (from $GOROOT)
    D:\dev\Gopher\src\build (from $GOPATH)
can't load package: package -o: cannot find package "-o" in any of:
    D:\dev\Go\src\-o (from $GOROOT)
    D:\dev\Gopher\src\-o (from $GOPATH)
can't load package: package d:/dev/Gopher/src/myproject.exe: cannot find package "d:/dev/Gopher/src/myproject.exe" in any of:
    D:\dev\Go\src\d:\dev\Gopher\src\myproject.exe (from $GOROOT)
    D:\dev\Gopher\src\d:\dev\Gopher\src\myproject.exe (from $GOPATH)
```

I can't seem to understand why it works one way, but not the other. The second method (for combined tasks) is outlined here: [Define multiple tasks in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046411/define-multiple-tasks-in-vscode)

---

Answer: The problem lies with adding "build" or "fmt" as an args when it's already listed as a taskname. I did not know that's how taskname worked. Final working product which allows users to develop without worrying about stupid windows firewalls:

tasks.json (final & working thanks to @not-a-golfer)

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"command": "go",
"echoCommand": true ,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": [
            "-o",
            "${workspaceRoot}.exe",
            "&&",
            "${workspaceRoot}.exe"
        ],
        "isBuildCommand": true
    },
    {
        "taskName": "fmt",
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to be working, but it appears that you can't chain the running with `&&`:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"command": "go",
"echoCommand": true ,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": [
            "-x",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceRoot}.exe"
        ],
        "isBuildCommand": true
    },
    {
        "taskName": "fmt",
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: adding "&&","${workspaceRoot}.exe" works for me. I'm guessing the problem had to do with me listing the taskname inside the args again. thank you!

Comment: @victoroux this taught me about this feature in vscode which I didn't know, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the attribute `suppressTaskName`.

OPs solution to remove superfluous `build` parameter obviously works, however, [VSCode's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) covers this very example:

> We set `suppressTaskName` to true as by default the task name is also passed to the command which would result in "echo hello Hello World".

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        { 
            "taskName": "hello",
            "args": ["Hello World"]
        },
        { 
            "taskName": "bye",
            "args": ["Good Bye"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite build task is:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"isShellCommand": true,
"showOutput": "always",
"command": "go",
"echoCommand": true ,
"options": {
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
},
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": [
            "build",
            "-x"
        ],
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "suppressTaskName": true
    }
]
}
```